# Passing a value to current Page

Tags: php, html

How do I check the url if it has a parameter or not before passing?
I need to pass the value of `s` on current page.
When passing on current page 'index.php' it would look like this  `index.php?s=value`
How can i pass the value if the url has parameters like `index.php?page=1` or `index.php?orderby=asc` so when i press the search button it would be something like this `index.php?page=1&s=value` or `index.php?orderby=asc&s=value`

```
<form  method="get">
            <p class="search-box">
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="user-search-input">Search Members:</label>
                <input type="search" id="user-search-input" name="s" value="" size="30" placeholder="Search">

                <input type="submit" name="" id="search-submit" class="button" value="Search Members">
            </p>

     </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php, you can output the param in the form as a hidden value, e.g. to keep the page param

```
<form  method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page']:''); ?>" />
```

Keep the htmlspecialchars when using $_GET['page'], or you will face XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Here, in `action` whole url will be placed.

```
<form  method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
```

You should keep current page as a `action along with query string, so that extra parameters will be added at last.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to include the page incomming parameters in the "action" attribute of you  tag.

Comment: If you didnt specify the action then the self will be the action of your form

Comment: <form action="index.php?page=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page']:'default'); ?>">...</form>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['s'])
{
    *dostuffwiths
   "echo <input type='hidden' name='s' value='$s'>";
}
else
{
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='s' value='$s'>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="GET">
<p class="search-box">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="user-search-input">Search Members:</label>
<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$s.'"><input type="search" id="user-search-input" name="s" value="" size="30" placeholder="Search"></a>
<input type="submit" name="" id="search-submit" class="button" value="Search Members">
</p>
</form>
```